# SQL Server - get values from X months ago according to columndata

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have the following table (data is completely fiction):

```
ID | MonthDate | PersonID | Name | Status  | MonthsAgoSinceLastCheck
1  | 2017-12   | 900      | Jack | Ill     | -
2  | 2018-01   | 900      | Jack | Ill     | 1
3  | 2018-02   | 900      | Jack | Ill     | 2
4  | 2018-03   | 900      | Jack | Healthy | 1
5  | 2017-02   | 901      | Bill | Ill     | -
6  | 2017-03   | 901      | Bill | Ill     | 1
7  | 2017-05   | 901      | Bill | Healthy | 1
```

For each record, I would like to see the previous status that person had X months ago since last check (column `MonthsAgoSinceLastCheck`). Notice that `MonthDate` can skip months.

So in this case, the result would be

```
ID | MonthDate | PersonID | Name | Status  | MonthsAgoSinceLastCheck | PreviousSatus
1  | 2017-12   | 900      | Jack | Ill     | -                       | -
2  | 2018-01   | 900      | Jack | Ill     | 1                       | Ill
3  | 2018-02   | 900      | Jack | Ill     | 2                       | Ill
4  | 2018-03   | 900      | Jack | Healthy | 1                       | Ill
5  | 2017-02   | 901      | Bill | Healthy | -                       | -
6  | 2017-03   | 901      | Bill | Healthy | 1                       | Healthy 
7  | 2017-05   | 901      | Bill | Ill     | 2                       | Healthy
```

Any sugestions/tips? I tried to do this with CTE's and self-joins but failed on both.

Comment: is MonthDate is DATE column.?

Answer (score 0):

It's way easier to use full dates than year and months separately. The first thing you should do is generate a full date from your year + month. Then just self join with previous month, depending on the last check.

```
;WITH DataWithDates AS
(
    SELECT
        T.ID,
        MonthDate = CONVERT(DATE, T.MonthDate + '-01'),
        T.PersonID,
        T.Name,
        T.Status,
        T.MonthsAgoSinceLastCheck
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
)
SELECT
    D.ID,
    D.MonthDate,
    D.PersonID,
    D.Name,
    D.Status,
    D.MonthsAgoSinceLastCheck,
    PreviousStatus = N.Status
FROM
    DataWithDates AS D
    LEFT JOIN DataWithDates AS N ON
        D.PersonID = N.PersonID AND
        N.MonthDate = DATEADD(MONTH, -1 * D.MonthsAgoSinceLastCheck, D.MonthDate)
```

I'm assuming your `MonthDate` has values for all rows, otherwise the conversion will fail. I'm also assuming that your `-` values for `MonthsAgoSinceLastCheck` are actually `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select *,LAG(Status) OVER(Partition by Name Order by MonthDate,Id) AS PreviousSatus
from tab1
order by id
```

SQl Fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/04407/4